# Detect tap on status bar while it is set to hidden

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll, statusbar

Currently my status bar is set to hidden, but i would like to have the scrollsToTop method working. Is there a workaround to keep the status bar hidden and detecting when it is tapped?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the status bar is hidden, the **built-in solution** with setting `scrollsToTop` to `YES` **will not work**.

> The scroll-to-top gesture is a tap on the status bar. When a user
>   makes this gesture, the system asks the scroll view closest to the
>   status bar to scroll to the top.

You have to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view and detect it yourself. 
You have two options:

- Add an invisible view of the size of the status bar and add a gesture recognizer to it.
- Add it to your main view and check if the tap occurred in the rectangle where normally status bar would be.

  ```
  - (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
  {
      CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

      if (CGRectContainsPoint(statusBarRect, p)) 
      {
          NSLog(@"Got a tap in the status bar area");

          // Scroll to the top.
          [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
      } 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You might instead consider just blending the status bar with your background (ie using the `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` on a white background or `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` on a dark background. Can't get around the low battery content, however).

Otherwise, I'd recommend creating your own `UIView` with alpha of zero and a `UITapGestureRecognizer` in place of the status bar, and implementing your own version of scrolling to top when you pick up a tapGesture.